# "given to" vs "marked by" vs "characterized by"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Based the definition I inferred from often seeing dictionary definitions of different words written using one or more of these three phrases, the three feel more or less the same.

While a quick google search shows up nothing useful, I would much appreciate if someone can give his or her opinion on this. It can be empirical or literary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intriguing observations. They are all very similar, yes. If you want to get into what the nuances of their distinctions might be, here are my thoughts / examples:

> He is a man **given to** wine. She is **given to** her beloved.

The word I think of when I hear that a person is "given to" something, is "dedication". It can of course be the good sort (given to a betrothed) or the bad (the bottle). Regardless, their fate is intertwined with whomever or whatever they are given to. They will be seen spending much of their free time with this subject.

> My mother is a woman **marked by** compassion. The merchant was **marked by** greed.

"Marked by" is interesting because it is very visual and implies that there is something so prevalent about a person that this quality is almost (if not literally) visible. In the literal sense you could have a dog marked by a scar. In the symbolic sense though, which is what you're more interested in I think, you have a characteristic so visible that it could even make itself known as you observe the person from a distance.

> The potassium tea is **characterized by** a distinct banana-like smell.

This final phrase is one that in my experience is usually describing a positive or neutral trait. I have rarely come across descriptions of things "characterized by" negative things or evil. I suppose this could be the result of the old adage "It's good for you, it builds character." If something or someone is characterized by a trait, they are easily classified by that thing. To me, it is the least dramatic of the three phrases.

**Final thoughts:** In all three phrases, this thing that they are marked by, given to, or characterized by is a core, inseparable part of who they are. This is usually in a way that to attempt to separate them from this quality would be traumatic like trying to tear off a limb. They would lose a part of themselves, who they really are, were this to happen.

Comment: Good discussion. I would add that "marked by" or "characterized by" can apply to person, place or thing; whereas "given to" applies only to sentient beings—entities who can be said to have preferences or proclivities.